# Concatenate Two double precisions into a string in sql server 2008 function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, concatenation

I have a Question regarding a Transact SQL Function. 
What I need is to combine two INT values into a VARCHAR value. E.g. Lower Limit = '5', Upper Limit = '15'
My result should be "5 - 15"

Table looks like this:
    ID     Lower Limit     Upper Limit
    1           5              15
    2           3              19
etc.

Code is like this so far.. All that there is left is to combine the two results:
Any help would be greatly appreciated !

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GiveMeTheRange] (@argID INT)

RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Range VARCHAR;
DECLARE @LowerLimit DOUBLE PRECISION;
DECLARE @UpperLimit DOUBLE PRECISION;


SELECT    @LowerLimit = [Lower Limit]
FROM         T_VormFactorKlassen
WHERE     (ID = (@argID)

SELECT    @UpperLimit = [Upper Limit]
FROM         T_VormFactorKlassen
WHERE     (ID = (@argID)


-- concattenate(@LowerLimit ' - ' @UpperLimit)  <----That ain't workin' 

RETURN @VormFactorKlasseNaam ;


END
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @VormFactorKlasseNaam = CAST(@LowerLimit as varchar(5)) + ' - ' + 
     cast(@UpperLimit as varchar(5))
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should avoid doing this kind of stuff with scalar functions. That said, this should work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GiveMeTheRange] (@argID INT)

RETURNS VARCHAR(23)   -- Always specify the length of the VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Range VARCHAR(23);
DECLARE @LowerLimit DOUBLE PRECISION;
DECLARE @UpperLimit DOUBLE PRECISION;


SELECT    @LowerLimit = [Lower Limit]
FROM         T_VormFactorKlassen
WHERE     ID = (@argID)

SELECT    @UpperLimit = [Upper Limit]
FROM         T_VormFactorKlassen
WHERE     ID = (@argID)


-- concattenate(@LowerLimit ' - ' @UpperLimit)  <----That ain't workin' 
SET @Range = CAST(@LowerLimit AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' - ' + 
             CAST(@UpperLimit AS VARCHAR(10))

RETURN @Range;


END
```

Comment: Thanks for that! works. 
What would you recommend should I wish to avoid such functions in the future?